# zsh complains about java_home.sh:6: not found

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

Every time I start a new terminal session on my mac, I receive the following error message:

`/Users/samerens/opt/anaconda3/etc/conda/activate.d/java_home.sh:6: = not found`

I can still type commands into the terminal and everything seems to work just fine, but I am curious what this error message means and if there is a way to make it go away. I checked and `java_home.sh` file does indeed exist and is located in the indicated directory, so I am not sure why I am receiving this error message. I am using macOS Catalina if it makes any difference.

EDIT: Here is the contents of `java_home.sh`

```
export CONDA_BACKUP_JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_HOME}"
export JAVA_HOME="${CONDA_PREFIX}"

export CONDA_BACKUP_JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

if [ $(uname) == Darwin ]; then
  export JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}"/jre/lib/server
else
  if [ $(uname -m) == x86_64 ]; then
    export JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}"/jre/lib/amd64/server
  else
    export JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${JAVA_HOME}"/jre/lib/i386/server
  fi
fi
```

Comment: And what is line 6 of `java_home.sh`? Include the whole file in the question if it's short.

Comment: I added the contents of `java_home.sh` to the original question.

Comment: Run that through https://shellcheck.net and fix any issues it points out. Should be a few.

Comment: Ran the file through ShellCheck and fixed the issues that it pointed out. I added a shebang line and quotes to prevent word splitting. However, I'm still receiving that same error message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ [ test == test ] ; echo $? 
zsh: = not found   
$ [ test = test ] ; echo $? 
0
```

Unlike bash, zsh doesn't recognize the equality test with double equals.
You can remove one of the equals sign in the both tests.
(I guess you need these environment variables in your zsh so running it with bash wouldn't help much.)

If this script is provided by anaconda install, this bug could be reported.